# CDbCommand: reduce value of column itself

Tags: php, yii

I would like to run SQL script with CDbCommand:

```
update user set point = point - 2 where user_id = 13 and role_id = 2;
```

And my code using Yii CDbCommand:

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->update(
  'user',
  array('point'=>'point + 2'),
  array('user_id' => 13, 'role_id'=>':role'),
  array('role'=>2)
);
```

Then I get the error:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens. The SQL statement executed was: UPDATE `user` SET `point`=:point
```

What is the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do:

```
$update = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->update('user',
        array(
            'point'=>new CDbExpression('point + 2')
        ),
        'id=:id AND role_id =:role_id',
        array(':id'=> 13, ':role_id' => 2)
    );
```

Comment: great! that's intersting. Tkz for your answer!